# How can I print a list with my own type of elements in OCaml?

Tags: list, printing, ocaml

Here is the type  of elements:

```
type listIS=Vide | I of int*listIS |S of string*listIS ;;

let l=I(5,I(3,S("3",I(0,S("",Vide)))));;
```

And my variant :

```
let rec afficheIS l=match l with
  |Vide ->""
  |I (i,l) -> (string_of_int i)^(afficheIS l)
  |S (s,l) -> (s)^(afficheIS l);;
```

But how can I change to give me the result :

```
5 3 3 0
-:unit = ()
```

Comment: I've updated my reply, after I've understood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've several suggestions, on how to improve your code.

First of all is the beauty, it matters for those who read the code (not for the compiler). Please, consider using spaces between lexemes. It will be much easier to read your code.

Next, there is no need to put this ;;

And then I'd like to suggest a more cleaner implementation of the printing function

```
open Printf

type listIS =
  | Vide
  | I of int * listIS
  | S of string * listIS


let rec fprintIS out l = match l with
  | Vide    -> fprintf out "\n"
  | I (i,l) -> fprintf out "%d %a" i fprintIS l
  | S (s,l) -> fprintf out "%s %a" s fprintIS l


let l=I(5,I(3,S("3",I(0,S("",Vide)))))

let printIS = fprintIS stdout
let () = printIS l
```

I hope that you're familiar with printf function. If not, then I can try to find out some other solution, that will be easier for you to understand.

In this solution (I've prettified the code, as you may noticed) I use "%a" format specifier. It requires two arguments: first is the function that prints a value of an arbitrary type and the second is the value of that type. Using specifier you can build combine your printers.

Comment: you've outputted an end-of-file to a standard output device. It won't affect the string, that you're trying to create from your data structure.

Comment: And, you've deleted a comment... Although, I'll leave it to you, just to make sure, that you understand a difference between string value, that is generated by your function, and the output of an interpreter, that is generated for each value you input.

Comment: I tried to put code in the comment because I'm not allowed to add answer just after 10 hours,but it wasn't idented like code so I edited my post.Thanks for your response

Comment: Thanks for your update! I'll keep in mind your remarks,I was thinking about using printf but I didn't used before %a, now I think I get it.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here: `let rec afficheIS l=function` your function `afficheIS` expect an argument `l` (that is never used) and you call `afficheIS` recursively you don't provide the `l` argument.
Actually this `l` corresponds to nothing so you should remove it.

Comment: Initally was match l with ,and after that I forgot to delete the argument "l".Now I have solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
 let rec afficheIS =function
      |Vide ->print_string "\n"
      |I (i,l) ->(print_string (string_of_int i));(afficheIS l);
      |S (s,l) -> print_string(s);(afficheIS l);;
```